# Prevent double form submissions in the backend ASP.NET Core 3.*

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying implement some kind of multiple from submission prevention in the backend of my ASP.NET Web application. I know you can apply javascript/jquery tricks in the frontend but i really want to go all the way and handle this in the backend also.

I'm using .NET Core 3 and PageModels.

I've looked up some examples here in stackoverflow but none seem to do the job for me. The closest i got was by overriding OnPageHandlerSelected which fires before the OnPost execution and as the documentation mentions before the model binding as well. I'm using the Antiforgery token to detect duplicate requests by saving the last token to the session and comparing the current token to the session's last token saved entry.

The problem right now is that the session string i'm trying to get, always retrieves null. By doing various quests i realized that i can only retrieve the stored session value after my OnPost method finishes executing but not before that. This of course creates a problem because my OnPost method can be long and take some time. I know i'm missing something out but i'm not sure what.

Any help along with some explanation is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Here is the PageModel code demonstrating this issue:
(Note that my Startup file has the AddSession and UseSession included)

**Test.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DoublePostApplication.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace DoublePostApplication
{

    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        public override void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Form.ContainsKey("__RequestVerificationToken"))
                {
                    var currentToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"].ToString();
                    var lastToken = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("LastProcessedToken");

                    if (lastToken == currentToken)
                    {
                        context.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Double form submission detected.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("LastProcessedToken", currentToken);
                    }

                }
            }

            base.OnPageHandlerSelected(context);
        }

        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            } else
            {
                return new BadRequestResult();
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### **Edit**

I managed to solve my problem by adding the following line of code right before i try to get the session value

```
context.HttpContext.Session.LoadAsync().Wait();
```

And the following line of code after i am setting the session value

```
context.HttpContext.Session.CommitAsync().Wait();
```

I believe what's happening is that i'm forcing session to store data somehow but i am not really sure what's happening. If someone cares to explain why the above 2 lines fix my problem i'll be more than happy to accept their answer. Please keep in mind that the problem, was preventing rapid firing of the submit button. Resubmission was being prevented just fine with the above code, after the form had been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem right now is that the session string i'm trying to get,
>   always retrieves null. By doing various quests i realized that i can
>   only retrieve the stored session value after my OnPost method finishes
>   executing but not before that.

First of all, make sure that the session value of `LastProcessedToken` has been set already.Then make sure that session has not expired yet. It works well when I try your code.

My startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? I tried your startup code but produces the same result. It works, once the form has been submitted (and it does prevent re-submission) but it still doesn't prevent rapid firing of the submit button. The way i'm testing it is i place a breakpoint in if (lastToken == currentToken) and when the breakpoint hits, i click the submit button again. When the breakpoint hits again after i continue the lastToken remains Null.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue but still not sure what's happening. Please have a look at my edit above. If you can explain to me what was going wrong i'll be more than happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @apoiat I could reproduce when resubmit form. IMO, The app retains a session for a limited time after the last request. Since the first post request has not completed when you resubmit, the session state will not be updated.Besides, your solution is named [Loading Session asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#load-session-state-asynchronously) which could deal with it.

Comment: If i follow the code through breakpoints the session value seems to exist/retain after it is initially set in the pagehandler all the way to the post execution. What seems strange is that the next request that's going to hit is not aware of the stored session value in the previous request. It only becomes aware of it after the previous request finishes executing. The moment you insert something into session, shouldn't it be immediately available to other requests as well, by the user? I probably need to dig deeper into how sessions work in asp.net core